# Variable not in scope: doubleMe :: [Integer] -> t (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

[image: Picture of the problem]

I don't know want's the problem with it. I just followed what the book stated. The book of [learn you a Haskell for Great Good] description is below:

> Say you have an immutable list of numbers xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and a function doubleMe which multiplies every element by 2 and then returns a new list. If we wanted to multiply our list by 8 in an imperative language and did
>   doubleMe(doubleMe(doubleMe(xs))) , it would probably pass through the list once and make a copy and then return it.

Comment: 1. ask a question, 2. please copy the error as text in the question, 3. where did you define `doubleMe`?

Comment: 4. what book? What exactly did you do?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time to ask questions on stackflow. I just refined the  question description. Thanks!

Comment: I think you understand the book the wrong way. It speaks of hypothetical lists and functions to demonstrate the difference between a functional and imperative program.

Answer (score 4):

`doubleMe` isn't a built-in function. The book *assumes* that you have defined it with something like

```
doubleMe = fmap (* 2)
```

(that's what "Say you have ..." means.)

You haven't defined the function yet, so the interpreter is telling you that `doubleMe` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

The book states:

> Say you have ...

This is in a hypothetical sense: both the list `xs` and the function `doubleMe`, do not exist as builtins in Haskell, the book aims to demonstrate that if we had such function, there is an important difference between how a Haskell interpreter will construct a new list (in a lazy manner), and an imperative equivalent would do that (construct three complete lists).

We can define this with:

```
Prelude> doubleMe = map (2*)
Prelude> xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Prelude> doubleMe xs
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]
```

So here we define `doubleMe` as `map (2*)` such that we multiply all elements. Probably the book explains that in Haskell, if we evaluate this, due to lazyness, we will never fully construct intermediate lists in case we call:

```
 Prelude> doubleMe (doubleMe (doubleMe xs))
[8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64]
```

Indeed, if we want to obtain the first list, we will evaluate the first item of `xs`, and each time mutliply it times two until we obtain eight.